# How can I set multiple full screens in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, fullscreen

I have one external monitor connected with my mac and I want to make a JavaFX app that is full screen in both my main monitor and external monitor.

I've tried the below code, but it always give me only one full screen at a time.

1. When the first setFullScreen(true) is called, the first stage appears full screen in my main monitor.
2. When the second setFullScreen(true) is called, the first stage lost its full screen and second stage appears full screen in the external monitor.

How can I set both stages as full screen at the same time in two monitors?

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        List<Screen> screens = Screen.getScreens();
        for (Screen screen : screens) {
            Rectangle2D screenBounds = screen.getBounds();
            Stage stage = new Stage();
            stage.setX(screenBounds.getMinX());
            stage.setY(screenBounds.getMinY());
            stage.setScene(new Scene(new Group()));
            stage.show();
            stage.setFullScreen(true);
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: have a look here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13030556/multiple-javafx-stages-in-fullscreen-mode

Answer (score 0):

Instead of explicitly going into full screen mode you could instead set the stage to be undecorated. You have already maximized the size. Isn't that enough then?